# Steel grade recommendation

Tags: materials, steel, corrosion

I'm working on a private project (no commercial motivations here) to build an outdoor (wood fired) pizza oven for my garden.

It's basically made of steel, so my question is which steel grade would be recommended for my application.

The steel plates should be able to withstand temperatures up to ~1000F/500C, without bending or visible deformations.

It should also be able to withstand occasional rains and snow in the winter. Climate in general is not too wet or too dry.

I made some research and based on it got some quotes for AISI 304 (3mm), but I'm still considering alternatives.

Thanks,
Juan

Comment: Why do wood stoves use cast iron plates inside or refractory material?

Comment: While stainless steel can tolerate higher temperatures, its relatively high thermal expansion coefficient concerns me if directly exposed to fire. Are you using any liner for your application?

Comment: Option # 2;  carbon steel with refractory lining. With the low stress, any cast iron or steel will be satisfactory at 1000 F. Stainless would look better. Magnetic stainless like 409 would be cheaper than 304 ,if you can get it .

Comment: Don't use anything zinc plated or galvanized. Heated zinc makes toxic fumes and residues.

Comment: I haven't considered any liner, but the plan is to use fire bricks inside the oven. This should increase the thermal mass and also avoid much (not all) direct exposure of the steel to the fire. I will check if I can get carbon steel with refractory lining or 409 steel. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: would the steel have enough thermal mass to bake the pizza?

Comment: Zinc oxide is not toxic , used in skin lotions.

Comment: I went with 304. After some tests, one panel is significantly bent and I'm planning to have it replaced. Which steel grade would you recommend, in order to avoid absolutely any deformation up to ~1000F/500C?

Comment: @blacksmith37 That's different from breathing it in.

Comment: If you inhale zinc oxide less than an hour old you get the "zinc chills" / "brass founders ague'.It goes away in 48 hours, been there , done that.

Answer (score 1):

Ferritic stainless ( 13 % Cr, 405, 409, etc) will be fine and cheaper than 304. Ferritic sheet metal was unusual decades ago, but uses in home appliances, auto exhaust, etc. has made sheet much more available. Actually if you could find an appliance junk yard, you could probable get a good  deal on ferritic sheet. Some Korean appliances are 304  but most all American appliances are cheap ferritic SS. Apologies for political incorrectness.

Answer (score 0):

food-grade steel.
304 grade stainless
18/8 or 18/10 stainless.

Comment: There is no such thing as "food grade" SS. There are SS traditionally used in food applications like 316 and 304.

Comment: I went with 304. It's generally fine, but one of the panels more exposed to heat is significantly bent and I'm going to have it replaced with some other alloy which resists these temperatures without any significant deformation.

Comment: I expect is is a thermal/geometry distortion  Nothing to do with the alloy composition.